# How can I force Akka.net Postgres persistence to reconnect

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

I am having some issues with persistent actors which use the Postgres plugin where it seems the actors never manage to reconnect to the database after a database outage.

The persistent actors are stopped after 1 minute of inactivity so I am getting new actors all the time, but they never seem to be able to reconnect.

Restarting the pod the actor system is running on fixes the problem.

I can kind of replicate this locally by :

- Stopping the database
- Starting the actor system
- Send a message which should force recovery
- Recovery fails because of no database connection

I then start the database without restarting the actor system and send a new message which spawns a new persistent actor which fails with the same database error.

Is there some way of forcing Akka.Persistence to reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go about solving this problem:

1. Recreate the entity actors using a [`BackoffSupervisor`](https://getakka.net/articles/persistence/event-sourcing.html#failures)  - which will recreate the actor according to an [exponential backoff schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-retries-exponential-backoff).
2. Or recreate the entity actors using the third party [Akka.Persistence.Extras NuGet package](https://github.com/petabridge/Akka.Persistence.Extras) which works similarly to the `BackoffSupervisor` but is able to save messages that weren't successfully persisted provided that you implement the messaging protocol it expects. The documentation for that feature is here: https://devops.petabridge.com/articles/state-management/akkadotnet-persistence-failure-handling.html